# SSE: How to publish data only when data changes

Tags: javascript, express, real-time, server-sent-events

I'm pretty new to SSE. Right now, I only know how to keep the stream open using a while(true) loop. How can I have my SSE stream only publish data when the underlying data changes? Below is the code I'm using.

```
const express = require('express');

run().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    const app = express();

app.get('/events', async function (req, res) {
    console.log('Got /events');
    res.set({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });
    res.flushHeaders();

    // Tell the client to retry every 10 seconds if connectivity is lost
    res.write('retry: 10000\n\n');
    let count = 0;

    while (true) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

        console.log('Emit', ++count);
        // Emit an SSE that contains the current 'count' as a string
        res.write(`data: ${count}\n\n`);
    }
});

await app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

}

EDIT:

I think I got what I was wanting. Modified the code to update clients when a new client connects to the stream:

```
const express = require('express');

run().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    const app = express();
    let connections = 0

    app.get('/events', async function (req, res) {
        console.log('Got /events');
        res.set({
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        });
        res.flushHeaders();

        connections += 1
        let localConnections = connections

        res.write(`data: ${connections}\n\n`);

        while (true) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

            if (localConnections !== connections) {
                localConnections = connections

                console.log('Emit', connections);
                // Emit an SSE that contains the current 'count' as a string
                res.write(`data: ${connections}\n\n`);

            }
        }
    });

    await app.listen(3000);
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
}
```

Comment: What is the underlying data?  If the data source doesn't tell you when something changes, then you  have to just keep the previous set of data in a variable and compare to see what has changed since you last sent it and then use that info to decide whether the data needs to be sent or not.

Comment: So I basically need to keep the while loop, but only publish data if it's changed is what I'm hearing? I was thinking for a quick POC just having some dictionary variable keeping track of people who connect under a certain ID.

Comment: Your `while` loop can work (because you're awaiting a promise in the loop), but more typically people will use `setInterval()` or repeated `setTimeout()` instead of the loop.  As to how to retain and test the data, you aren't showing anything about the data, where it comes from or what differences you're looking for so we can't really help with that.

Comment: In a nutshell, only call `res.write()` when the data has changed and you have something new/changed to send.